# How to add to a table based on id of previous insert- having problems with mysqli_insert_id

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to add a user to a users table based on some values from a form. Then, I want to use the auto-incremented userID to add data to a passwords table.

My code is as follows:

```
$addQuery = "INSERT INTO vle_users (typeID, username, email, forename, surname) VALUES ('3', '$uname', '$email', '$fname', '$sname')";
$addResult = mysqli_query($conn,$addQuery) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$userId = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
$pwQuery = "INSERT INTO vle_passwords (userID, password) VALUES ('$userID',   MD5('$pw'))";
 $pwResult = myqli_query($conn,$pwQuery) or die (mysqli_error($conn));
```

However, the issue appears to be occurring at:
    `$userID = mysqli_insert_id($conn);`
When I try echoing out that `$userID`, I just get an undefined variable notice. The data goes into the user table correctly before then.

I'm really stumped as to how to proceed from here. Any help would be invaluable.

Comment: $userID != $userId

Comment: Use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` for saving and checking user passwords. See http://www.php.net/password_hash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you storing in variable `$userId = mysqli_insert_id($conn);` but in query `$pwQuery = "INSERT INTO vle_passwords (userID, password) VALUES ('$userID',   MD5('$pw'))";` you are using `$userID` variable . so that's why you are getting error of undefined variable.
Second change `$pwResult = myqli_query($conn,$pwQuery) or die (mysqli_error($conn));` to `$pwResult = mysqli_query($conn,$pwQuery) or die (mysqli_error($conn));`
Hope it will help you.